# Не скрывает элемент по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, события

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По нажатию на `div` с классом `.game-image-description` должен выезжать текст с классом `.hide-text`.

Текст выезжает, однако, когда я нажимаю на кнопку с класом `.close-description-btn` (зелёный крестик в правом верхнем углу) текст не скрывается.

В чём проблема?

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.game-image-description');
// text.removeAttribute("style");
for (let btn of btns) {
  btn.onclick = () => {
    const text = btn.parentElement.querySelector('.hide-text');
    text.style.marginBottom = '0px';
  };
}

const btnClose = document.querySelectorAll('.close-description-btn');
for (let btn of btnClose) {
  btn.onclick = () => {
    const text = btn.closest('.hide-text');
    text.style.marginBottom = '-100%';
  };
}
```

```html
<article class="game-item">
  <h3 class="game-item__rank">Rank <span class="rank-number">3</span></h3>
  <div class="game-item__image">
    <div class="game-image-description">
      <p itemprop="description" class="hide-text">
        <button class="close-description-btn">✖</button> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
        ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiatnulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="game-item__button">read review</button>
  </a>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведенным ниже блоке кода Вы вешаете событие onclick на div целиком, что не дает возможности нажать на крестик впоследствии:

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".game-image-description")

for (let btn of btns) {
  btn.onclick = () => {
    const text = btn.parentElement.querySelector(".hide-text")
    text.style.marginBottom = 0
  }
}
```

Без этого все работает:

```js
const handleClick = event => {
  event.target.closest(".hide-text").style.display = "none"
}

document.querySelectorAll(".close-description-btn").forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", handleClick))
```

```html
<article class="game-item">
  <h3 class="game-item__rank">Rank <span class="rank-number">3</span></h3>
  <div class="game-item__image">
    <div class="game-image-description">
      <p itemprop="description" class="hide-text">
        <button class="close-description-btn">✖</button> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
        ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiatnulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="game-item__button">read review</button>
  </a>
</article>
```

Вариант решения:

```js
const handleClick = event => {
  const target = event.target
  if (target.classList.contains("close-description-btn")) {
    target.closest(".hide-text").style.display = "none"
    return false
  }
  const ht = target.querySelector(".hide-text")
  if (ht.style.display === "none") {
    ht.style.display = "block"
  }

}

document.querySelectorAll(".game-image-description").forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", handleClick))
```

```html
<article class="game-item">
  <h3 class="game-item__rank">Rank <span class="rank-number">3</span></h3>
  <div class="game-item__image">
    <div class="game-image-description">временно видимая часть контейнера на которую можно нахать что бы показался текст целиком
      <p itemprop="description" class="hide-text" style="display: none;">
        <button class="close-description-btn">✖</button> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
        ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiatnulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="game-item__button">read review</button>
  </a>
</article>
```

Comment: А на что мне поставить эвент. Он должен быть на блоке.
Вы можете посмотреть фото. По нажатию на черную область должен всплывать текст, по нажатию на крест исчезать.

Comment: Работает. Проблема в том, что надо создать текст внутри `game-image-description`. Иначе это не работает. Внутри есть img, но почему то этого не достаточно.
А мне надо что бы там только картинка была.

Comment: @Samalamadoit В Вашем вопросе вы спрашиваете `почему не закрывается блок?`. Вам стоит переписать существующий вопрос так что бы он отражал реальную проблему либо задать новый, так как все о чем Вы спрашивали в этом я объяснил и решил.